# JavaCompiler always null with JDK versions > 1.8.0

Tags: java

I get the `JavaCompiler` using the following:

```
System.setProperty("java.home", "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home");
javax.tools.JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

I tried this with:

> jdk1.8.0_144.jdk
>
> jdk1.8.0_162.jdk
>
> jdk-9.0.4.jdk
>
> jdk-10.jdk
>
> jdk-11.jdk

For `1.8.0` the compiler never works cause the following file is missing:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/currency.data`

For every JDK after `1.8.0` the compiler is always null.

I also only find a `tools.jar` in `1.8.0`.

Does anyone know a way to get the JavaCompiler working no matter what idk?

Comment: You need to add a certain module when running, as explained in [the method’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler--).

Comment: @VGR I do not get what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your `module-info.java` file has a requirement for the `jdk.compiler` module:

```
module myModule {
    requires jdk.compiler;
}
```

---

According to the [documentation for `getSystemJavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler--):

> This implementation returns the compiler provided by the `jdk.compiler`
>   module if that module is available, and `null` otherwise.